# Python Grab The Second Value, Ignore The First

Tags: python

I am developing a function using Python scripting to grab a value from another text file.

The text file contains :

```
GR6VN=MOD,KYBD,79,US,ENG,M20ISU-BS
18YPJ=KYBD,79,US,ENG,M20ISU-BS
X903C=INFO,RYLTY,KYBD,BLIT,XLOB
R609C=MOD,CORD,PWR,125V,1M,C5,US
K260C=CORD,PWR,125V,2.5A,1M,C5,US
RNV1F=MOD,ADPT,AC,65W,LTON,EPT,PECOS
```

I would like to grab only the value ***CORD,PWR,125V,2.5A,1M,C5,US*** without the ***"K260C="***. However, the result that I get when using my code function is ***['R609C', 'MOD,CORD,PWR,125V,1M,C5,US\r\nK260C', 'CORD,PWR,125V,2.5A,1M,C5,US']***.

Below is my code :

```
  psu = ""
  KEYWORDS="CORD,PWR"

  MATCHLINE=cfi_tools.cfi_textfind(KEYWORDS, HCF_INI)
  if MATCHLINE <> []:
    for LINE in MATCHLINE:
        line=string.split(MATCHLINE,"=")
        psu = line
        #psu = line2.replace('CORD,PWR,', '')
    print psu
  else:
    cfi_tools.cfi_fail("Cannot find expected keywords: " + KEYWORDS)

  if (psu == ""):
      psu = "N/A"
      cfi_tools.cfi_log("NO psu info got from GCF THEREFORE UNKNOWN RECORDED" ,"LOG")
  else:
      cfi_tools.cfi_log(" PSU Info FOUND IN GCF IS %s" % (psu),"LOG")
```

Anything I can do so that I can ignore the first line and only take the second one?

Comment: incidentally, convention is to use capitals for constants, not variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would be to directly specify the array element you want:

`line=string.split(MATCHLINE,"=")[1]`

[0] = K260C
[1] = CORD,PWR,125V,2.5A,1M,C5,US

Comment: I don't think he wants it as array, just the value but yes this would be an option

Comment: I was a complete idiot, thought the whole line was `=` separated, sorry.

Comment: @mlueckl there are two lines with "CORD,PWR," string. How would I like to capture only the second one? Per this suggestion, it would grab the value MOD,CORD,PWR,125V,1M,C5,US instead.

Comment: @WinterBucky you could do another for-loop on the line and match this or use the KEYWORDS as a delimiter on the line-string and just rebuild the outcome by adding the KEYWORDS.